# How to match everything except for specified strings?

Tags: regex, grep-indesign

Ok so I'm really  struggling to figuring this one out. There where other post on here answering this question but non of them worked out for my use case (GREP InDesign).

```
Input:

meelebox meelebox meeleboxmeeleduelist meeleboxuser meelebox meelebox meelebox
```

--

```
Match:

meele meele meelemeeleduelist meeleuser meele meele meele
```

I got `\w+(?=(box))|(?<=box)\w+` to work, but I really want an expression where I only need to write the word once, as it's an expression I use a lot and that might change over time.

I thought I figured it out with this `\w+(?=(box))|(?<=\2)\w+` but the `\2` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Like this? [`(box)|.`](https://regex101.com/r/ekkaRN/1) will help to add some context :)

Comment: With PCRE  `(?(DEFINE)(?<b>box))(?:\w+(?=(?&b))|(?&b)\K\w+)` https://regex101.com/r/b5lu98/1 What should be the match for `meleeboxbox` ?

Comment: Sorry guys, I wrote the match wrong. it's suppose to Exclude the string "box" so match would be: meele meele meelemeeleduelist meeleuser meele meele meele

Comment: But it does give you those matches right? https://regex101.com/r/8pbUYX/1

Comment: [Some variation](https://regex101.com/r/xNxhKP/1) of @the4thbird's idea. I was playing with it again xD Funnily on my first reading I've totally overlooked that your main reason is to not use the word `box` a second time. If you added more context there might be some other solution such as [just using capuring groups](https://regex101.com/r/VlxH2K/1).

Answer (score 1):

The problem you defined doesn't even require RegEx. It can be solved using simple string replace, where you replace occurrences of `box` with an empty string.

```
❯ echo "meelebox meelebox meeleboxmeeleduelist meeleboxuser meelebox meelebox meelebox" | sed s/box//g
meele meele meelemeeleduelist meeleuser meele meele meele
```

Comment: that may be true, but I require a RegEx solution. Im applying a character style with grep in indesign.